# Как вывести в консоль строку, которую потом можно будет изменять? C++

Tags: c++, строки, консоль

Я новичок и создаю простейший консольный ТуДу Лист на плюсах. Хочу создать метод, изменяющий выбранную задачу(в случае опечатки например). При этом хочется чтобы в консоль выводилось предыдущее содержимое этой задачи, которое можно было бы изменять, а затем считать и отправить исправленный вариант. Всё это чтобы не пришлось перепечатывать задачу заново из-за мелкой ошибки. Пока он просто выводит прошлую строку без возможности изменения.
Есть ли возможность подобное реализовать?

```
    void ChangingTask(){
        cout << "Which task you want to change?\n";
        cout << "0. Back\n";
        cin >> TaskNumber;
        if(TaskNumber == 0){
                return ShowMainMenu();
        }
        else if(TaskNumber < 0 || TaskNumber > allTasks.size()){
            cout << "Incorrect task number!\n\n";
            return ChangingTask();
        }

        cout << allTasks[TaskNumber]
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, singleTask);
        allTasks[TaskNumber - 1] = singleTask;
        ChangedOrNot = true;
        return ShowMainMenu();
        }
```

Comment: Нет. С помощью стандартных потоков ввода/вывода задача не реализуема.

Comment: Какая платформа?

Comment: Я как-то писал функцию редактирования текста. Там нужна только одна функция Windows, GoToXY которая устанавливает и сдвигает курсор от кнопок. Кнопки право, лево ловятся char ch=getch(); if (kbhit) ch=getch(); так можно отловить нажатие расширенных клавиш. Указатель бегает по массиву, при нажатии срабатывает Insert, Delete, BackSpace функции, вставляя и удаляя символы из строки. С перерисовкой её по GoToXY координатам.

Comment: void Gotoxy(const int X,const int Y)
{
    HANDLE OutputHandle;
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO ScreenBufInfo;
    OutputHandle=GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(OutputHandle,&ScreenBufInfo);
    ScreenBufInfo.dwCursorPosition.X=X;
    ScreenBufInfo.dwCursorPosition.Y=Y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(OutputHandle,ScreenBufInfo.dwCursorPosition);
}

Comment: Посмотрите https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline

Comment: @FrancNet, ещё необходимо узнать ширину экрана и реагировать на изменение этой ширины.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте отлавливать нажатие backspace. например, так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>
#define BACKSPACE 8
#define ESC 27 

std::string EditText(std::string text) {
    std::cout << text;
    while (true) {
        int inp = _getch();
        if (inp == BACKSPACE) {
            text = text.substr(0, text.length()-1);
        }
        else if (inp == ESC) {
            return text;
        }
        else {
            text += inp;
        }
        system("cls");
        std::cout << text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Строчный редактор с редактированием командами. В примере программа в цикле печатает строку, позицию курсора и приглашение для ввода команды. Пользователь печатает команду, жмёт Enter. Например:

> ```
> Купить свежую рыбу.             # строка которую предлагается редактировать
> -                               # позиция курсора
> > w                             # команда "курсор на следующее слово"
> Купить свежую рыбу.             # программа печатает строку снова
>        -                        # положение курсора изменилось
> > cw консервированную           # "change word" и аргумент
> Купить консервированную рыбу.   # слово над курсором замено новым текстом
>                        -        # курсор тоже подвинулся
> > u                             # отменить последнюю команду
> Купить свежую рыбу.             # правка отменена
>        -                        # положение курсора вернулось
> > q                             # редактирование завершилось
> ```

Нужны команды для перемещения курсора (`0 h l w b e $ f F ;`), для редактирования (`d x X r i I a A c dw cw y yw p P s/.../.../`), для отмены/повтора команд (`u U uu UU`).

**P.S.** Я вимер (пользователь [Vim](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim)) - мне будет удобно. Если вы привыкли к редактированию на экране, то придётся попотеть.

**P.P.S.** Не нужно топать ногами, если вам не удобно. Я всё понимаю, нормальный строчный редактор удобнее. Предложенный вариант хорош тем что его можно реализовать на стандартном C/C++ и он будет работать везде. Строчные редакторы зависят от платформы. Ни одного переносимого я не нашёл.

Comment: Пишут, что [readline](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline) кросс-платформенный (и history к нему есть в соседней коробке)

Comment: readline на Windows работает через CygWin. Это очень условная переносимость.

Comment: Был бы я виндузятником, давно бы перенес в native (или это взаимно-исключающие характеристики? -))

Comment: @avp, там есть вещи простые - навигация в строке, редактирование. Вот их можно сделать переносимо. Это отличный проект для пары человек на пару недель.